# mysql table into List

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

i use **c#**, **winform** and **mysql** database.
And i have a table **t_class** in like below

```
id        class       group      name        surname
1         10          1          joe         philips
2         10          2          maya        edwards
3         10          4          michael     collins
4         11          3          sasha       ivanko
5         10          2          araz        kurio
etc...
```

and i have a class **MyClass** like this

```
class MyClass
{
    int class;
    int group;
    string name;
    string surname;
}
```

there is a List

```
List<MyClass>  myclass = new List<MyClass>();
```

Can you tell me please,
how can i load data from t_table into this list.

i wolud like to use LINQ there.
and not looping in datatable rows for this.

Comment: First create a `constructor` to initialize values or properties for the data values. then loop through `dataset table` that you fetched from db and use `myclass.add( new MyClass(Int32.Parse(dr["class"])......));` inside the loop. it will fill you list with the object of `MyClass corresponding to your tables rows.

Answer (score 1):

You should have to use `Linq-Sql` or Entity Data model. In case if not then you have to populate `DataTable` using Data provider classes (DataAdapter).

Add public properties or argument constructor.

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Class {get;set;}
    public int Group {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string SurName {get;set;}
}

var result = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                      select new MyClass
                       {
                        Class=row.Field<int>("class"),
                        Group=row.Field<int>("group"),
                        Name=row.Field<string>("name"),
                        SurName=row.Field<string>("surname")
                        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Well `LINQ to SQL` would be ideal choice but as you have `MySQL` so you won't have out of the box support in that case. Although you can explore [Linq Provider for MySql](http://code2code.net/DB_Linq/)

Other option could be to retrieve the `DataTable` from Database using `SQL Query`. Then iterate through retrieved `DataTable` and for each row create new instance of `MyClass` and populate the values from column values of `DataTable`

```
  //pseudocode
        List<MyClass> list = new ...

        foreach(DataRow row in retrievedDataTable)
        {
            MyClass instance = new MyClass();
            instance.ID = row["ID"];
            similarly for rest of the properties

            list.Add(instance);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the DataReader for it

So that , you can use the linq to retrive the data .

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> GetEntity<T>() where T : new ()
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader ...)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                 T t = new T();

                 var values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
                 reader.GetValues(values);

                 for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                 {
                     t.GetType().GetProperty(reader.GetName(i)).SetValue(t, values[i], null);
                 }

                 yield return t;
            }
        }
    }
```